# Node fs check if sub directory exists

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to check if a sub directory exists, which could be n number of directories nested.  `fs.access()` and `fs.existsSync` are working for top level directories, for instance:

`fs.existsSync('firstDirectory') => true`

but

`fs.existsSync('parentDirectory/childDirectory') => false` even though it does exist.

What is the best way to check if a nested directory exists from the current working directory?

Comment: What platform are you using? Just tried on a mac and your example worked for me.